# I want to reflect multiple content files on a particular site, but only one of them is reflected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
"manifest_version": 3,
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://www.test.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "test-1.js"
            ]
        },
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://www.test.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "test-2.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
```

For example, if I set up a manifest as shown above, the JS file for test-1 is not reflected, but only the JS file for test-2 is reflected.
Is there any way to reflect both somehow?
Thank you in advance for your cooperation.

Comment: Both files should be injected normally. The problem may be caused by 1) a bug in Chrome, 2) an invisible whitespace character in `matches`, 3) your actual `matches` are different and the site is using fake navigation via history.pushState or #hash, 4) test-1.js has an error.

Comment: If I change the position of test-1.js and test-2.js, test-1.js will be reflected, so I think there is no problem with the JS file or Manifest. (Deepl)

Comment: There's nothing I can add without seeing a **real** [MCVE](/help/mcve).